# 3D CGI film with robot mecha that move the way the pilots move, and the pilots share damage with them

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, mecha

The mecha are unique and one boy finds an ancient robot. Few people have mecha and one is an arrogant blond boy. At the end, one guy sacrifices himself and is stabbed with glowing tentacles. I think the animation is like *Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: i think its early 2000. I think i watched it on dvd.

Comment: Gridman has a similar plot, but is 2d animation; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMVH4bvG5GM

Comment: thats not it it was 3d cgi film

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[Elysium](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0356577/)*** (2003)...?

From the [English Voice Over Wikia](https://english-voice-over.fandom.com/wiki/Elysium_(2003)):

> Elysium is a 2003 animated science fiction film by director Kwon Jae-sung. The film was released on February 24, 2003 at the Fantasporto Film Festival.

From IMDB:

> Elysium is the name of a planet which is to invade Earth. A scientist newly found this planet around AD 2113, which is located at the end of the Galaxy and they gave it the name of Elysium. The story is about the message, only love for humanity can save the earth. But, the humans, in an aggressive and resistant historical situation with the motive of brave warrior's adventures, saving the human race from the attacks of outer world.

It's a 3D-animated movie from the right time period, and features various characters piloting mechanised armours, including a blond boy.

Near the end of the film, the boy and two other guys in these armours battle a villain, also in armour, who projects tentacles as his primary weapons. The blond kid is about to get skewered by the tentacles at one point, but one of his allies steps in the way and is stabbed instead.

You can view the scene in question at around the 1:13:35 mark in the video below.

Comment: OMG!!! Yes thats it! Thank you!!! Now i can finally sleep thank you!